# Swap BEP-20 based tokens with 0x and ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, 0x, swaps

I am trying to swap BEP-20 based tokens with 0x and Ethers.js.

https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote

I used this endpoint to get quote of the exchange.

https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xF8fC63200e181439823251020d691312FDcF5090&buyToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&sellAmount=10000000000000

From the above link, I can get the following JSON object.

```
{
    "chainId": 56,
    "price": "0.000000697723740987",
    "guaranteedPrice": "0.000000690746503577",
    "to": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
    "data": "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",
    "value": "0",
    "gas": "136000",
    "estimatedGas": "136000",
    "gasPrice": "5000000000",
    "protocolFee": "0",
    "minimumProtocolFee": "0",
    "buyTokenAddress": "0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
    "sellTokenAddress": "0xf8fc63200e181439823251020d691312fdcf5090",
    "buyAmount": "6977237409872971",
    "sellAmount": "10000000000000",
    "sources": [
        {
            "name": "BakerySwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Belt",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "DODO",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "DODO_V2",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ellipsis",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mooniswap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "MultiHop",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nerve",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "PancakeSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "PancakeSwap_V2",
            "proportion": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "SushiSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Smoothy",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "ApeSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "CafeSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "CheeseSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "JulSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "LiquidityProvider",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "WaultSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "FirebirdOneSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "JetSwap",
            "proportion": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "ACryptoS",
            "proportion": "0"
        }
    ],
    "orders": [
        {
            "makerToken": "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c",
            "takerToken": "0xf8fc63200e181439823251020d691312fdcf5090",
            "makerAmount": "6977237409872971",
            "takerAmount": "10000000000000",
            "fillData": {
                "tokenAddressPath": [
                    "0xf8fc63200e181439823251020d691312fdcf5090",
                    "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c"
                ],
                "router": "0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e"
            },
            "source": "PancakeSwap_V2",
            "sourcePathId": "0x815ef5c1e45481227d1abef5571ff9f920022448699927968091f831e4cba126",
            "type": 0
        }
    ],
    "allowanceTarget": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff",
    "sellTokenToEthRate": "0",
    "buyTokenToEthRate": "1"
}
```

I just need to confirm the transaction with Ethers.js but I am not sure how to send this JSON data with Ethers.js

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `to`, `data`, `value`, `gasPrice` and `gas` fields to construct an Ethers transaction, sign it and send it.

Most javascript frameworks allow passing in the entire response and it will pluck out the needed values. I would consult the Ethers.js documentation for more info and examples.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Jacob.

I sent it with Ethers.js but it was reverted. 
Could you check this tx history?
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc26f700ea89d56d0b240f49a5101530ae25dc00dd037fbf38f2fe6a0ecf1ab4f